# tilde isn't responsive in iTerm after configuring a hotkey window

Tags: terminal, iterm2

I've read and applied all the instructions in this [post](https://www.typefloundry.com/1-800-iterm-bling.html) to configure a hotkey window. I've managed to configure it but when typing a tilde(~) it's not responsive in iTerm's hotkey window. Note that the tilde(~) works okay in the default window. But when I invoke the hotkey window it doesn't type the tilde(~). Instead, it makes a keyboard blocking sound.

I'm probably missing something simple here, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My issue was solved after following these steps:

1. Go to Preferences > Profiles
2. Select your profile
3. Got to keys tab
4. Modify the Right Option key from Esc+ to Normal.
   [image]